# How can I get validation messages to render on collection properties when using new guid indexes each time?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

In this example ASP.Net MVC 4 program I have a user fill in details about a horse race. The race has a name a well as a list of horses involved. Each horse has a name and an age.

The form uses ajax and javascript to allow the person to add and delete horse input fields on the fly, which is then submitted all at once when the submit button is pressed.

To make this process easy for me, I'm using an [html helper](http://www.mattlunn.me.uk/blog/2014/08/how-to-dynamically-via-ajax-add-new-items-to-a-bound-list-model-in-asp-mvc-net/) made by [Matt Lunn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/444991/matt).

```
public static MvcHtmlString EditorForMany<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, IEnumerable<TValue>>> expression, string htmlFieldName = null) where TModel : class
{
    var items = expression.Compile()(html.ViewData.Model);
    var sb = new StringBuilder();

    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(htmlFieldName))
    {
        var prefix = html.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix;

        htmlFieldName = (prefix.Length > 0 ? (prefix + ".") : String.Empty) + ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);
    }

    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        var dummy = new { Item = item };
        var guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

        var memberExp = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(Expression.Constant(dummy), dummy.GetType().GetProperty("Item"));
        var singleItemExp = Expression.Lambda<Func<TModel, TValue>>(memberExp, expression.Parameters);

        sb.Append(String.Format(@"<input type=""hidden"" name=""{0}.Index"" value=""{1}"" />", htmlFieldName, guid));
        sb.Append(html.EditorFor(singleItemExp, null, String.Format("{0}[{1}]", htmlFieldName, guid)));
    }

    return new MvcHtmlString(sb.ToString());
}
```

While I don't understand all the details (please read the blog post), I do know that it changes the index values into guids rather than sequential integers. This allows me to delete items in the middle of the list without needing to recalculate indexes.

Here is the rest of my code for my MCVE

HomeController.cs

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new Race();

        //start with one already filled in
        model.HorsesInRace.Add(new Horse() { Name = "Scooby", Age = 10 });

        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(Race postedModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
            //model is valid, redirect to another page
            return RedirectToAction("ViewHorseListing");
        else
            //model is not valid, show the page again with validation errors
            return View(postedModel);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult AjaxMakeHorseEntry()
    {
        //new blank horse for ajax call
        var model = new List<Horse>() { new Horse() };
        return PartialView(model);
    }
}
```

Models.cs

```
public class Race
{
    public Race() { HorsesInRace = new List<Horse>(); }

    [Display(Name = "Race Name"), Required]
    public string RaceName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Horses In Race")]
    public List<Horse> HorsesInRace { get; set; }
}

public class Horse
{
    [Display(Name = "Horse's Name"), Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Horse's Age"), Required]
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Index.cshtml

```
@model CollectionAjaxPosting.Models.Race
<h1>Race Details</h1>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary()
    <hr />
    <div>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(x => x.RaceName)
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.RaceName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.RaceName)
    </div>
    <hr />
    <div id="horse-listing">@Html.EditorForMany(x => x.HorsesInRace)</div>
    <button id="btn-add-horse" type="button">Add New Horse</button>
    <input type="submit" value="Enter Horses" />
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        //add button logic
        $('#btn-add-horse').click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("AjaxMakeHorseEntry")',
                cache: false,
                method: 'GET',
                success: function (html) {
                    $('#horse-listing').append(html);
                }
            })
        });

        //delete-horse buttons
        $('#horse-listing').on('click', 'button.delete-horse', function () {
            var horseEntryToRemove = $(this).closest('div.horse');
            horseEntryToRemove.prev('input[type=hidden]').remove();
            horseEntryToRemove.remove();
        });

    });
</script>
```

Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/Horse.cshtml

```
@model CollectionAjaxPosting.Models.Horse

<div class="horse">
    <div>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(x => x.Name)
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Name)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Name)
    </div>
    <div>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(x => x.Age)
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Age)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Age)
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="delete-horse">Remove Horse</button>
    <hr />
</div>
```

Views/Home/AjaxMakeHorseEntry.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<CollectionAjaxPosting.Models.Horse>

@Html.EditorForMany(x => x, "HorsesInRace")
```

The data flow works with this code. A person is able to create and delete horse entries as much as they want on the page, and when the form is submitted all entered values are given to the action method.

However, if the user does not enter in the `[Required]` information on a horse entry, `ModelState.IsValid` will be false showing the form again, but **no validation messages will be shown** for the Horse properties. The validation error do show up in the `ValidationSummary` list though.

For example, if `Race Name` is left blank, along with one `Horse's Name`, a validation message will be shown for the former. The latter will have a validation `<span>` with the class "field-validation-valid".

[image]

I'm very sure this is caused because the `EditorForMany` method creates new guids for each property each time the page is created, so validation messages can't be matched to the correct field.

What can I do to fix this? Do I need to abandon guid index creation or can an alteration be made to the `EditorForMany` method to allow validation messages to be passed along correctly?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I'm very sure this is caused because the `EditorForMany` method creates new guids for each property each time the page is created, so validation messages can't be matched to the correct field.

Yep; that's exactly what is happening here.

To fix this, we need to amend `EditorForMany()` so that it re-uses the GUID for an item, rather than generating a new one. In turn, this means we need to track what GUID has been assigned to what item, so that it can be re-used.

The former can be accomplished by internal modifications to `EditorForMany()`. The latter requires us to:

1. Add a property to our models in which the assigned GUID can be stored
2. Add a parameter to `EditorForMany()` to tell the helper which property contains the GUID to re-use (if any).

This leaves the `EditorForMany` helper looking like this;

```
public static class HtmlHelperExtensions
{
    public static MvcHtmlString EditorForMany<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, IEnumerable<TValue>>> propertyExpression, Expression<Func<TValue, string>> indexResolverExpression = null, string htmlFieldName = null) where TModel : class
    {
        htmlFieldName = htmlFieldName ?? ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(propertyExpression);

        var items = propertyExpression.Compile()(html.ViewData.Model);
        var htmlBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        var htmlFieldNameWithPrefix = html.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(htmlFieldName);
        Func<TValue, string> indexResolver = null;

        if (indexResolverExpression == null)
        {
            indexResolver = x => null;
        }
        else
        {
            indexResolver = indexResolverExpression.Compile();
        }

        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            var dummy = new { Item = item };
            var guid = indexResolver(item);
            var memberExp = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(Expression.Constant(dummy), dummy.GetType().GetProperty("Item"));
            var singleItemExp = Expression.Lambda<Func<TModel, TValue>>(memberExp, propertyExpression.Parameters);

            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(guid))
            {
                guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                guid = html.AttributeEncode(guid);
            }

            htmlBuilder.Append(String.Format(@"<input type=""hidden"" name=""{0}.Index"" value=""{1}"" />", htmlFieldNameWithPrefix, guid));

            if (indexResolverExpression != null)
            {
                htmlBuilder.Append(String.Format(@"<input type=""hidden"" name=""{0}[{1}].{2}"" value=""{1}"" />", htmlFieldNameWithPrefix, guid, ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(indexResolverExpression)));
            }

            htmlBuilder.Append(html.EditorFor(singleItemExp, null, String.Format("{0}[{1}]", htmlFieldName, guid)));
        }

        return new MvcHtmlString(htmlBuilder.ToString());
    }
}
```

We also then need to change our models, to add a property in which the GUID is stored;

```
public class Race
{
    public Race() { HorsesInRace = new List<Horse>(); }

    [Display(Name = "Race Name"), Required]
    public string RaceName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Horses In Race")]
    public List<Horse> HorsesInRace { get; set; }
}

public class Horse
{
    [Display(Name = "Horse's Name"), Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Horse's Age"), Required]
    public int Age { get; set; }

    // Note the addition of Index here.
    public string Index { get; set; }
}
```

... and lastly, change our usage of `EditorForMany()` to use the new signature;

*Index.cshtml*;

```
<div id="horse-listing">@Html.EditorForMany(x => x.HorsesInRace, x => x.Index)</div>
```

*AjaxMakeHorseEntry.cshtml*;

```
@Html.EditorForMany(x => x, x => x.Index, "HorsesInRace")
```

... which should then make the validation messages appear.

---

<sup>As an aside, I recommend not using the `htmlFieldName` parameter for `EditorForMany`, and instead changing your controller action to;</sup>

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult AjaxMakeHorseEntry()
{
    var model = new Race();

    model.HorsesInRace.Add(new Horse());
    return PartialView(model);
}
```

... then your *AjaxMakeHorseEntry.cshtml* view to be just;

```
@model Models.Race

@Html.EditorForMany(x => x.HorsesInRace, x => x.Index)
```

<sup>Otherwise, the generated `name` attributes break when nesting usage of `EditorForMany()`.</sup>

<sup>I'm going to update the blog post to use the above version of `EditorForMany()`, less the acceptance of the `htmlFieldName` parameter, for this reason.</sup>